# Override a method in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, overriding, getter

I'm trying to override a getter in Objective-C. I have two classes, `First` and `Second`, like:

`First.h`:

```
@interface First : MashapeResponse {
    NSString* message;
}

@property(readwrite, retain) NSString* message;

@end
```

`First.m`:

```
#import "First.h"

@implementation First

@synthesize message;

@end
```

`Second.h`:

```
#import "First.h"

@interface Second : First

-(NSString*) message;

@end
```

`Second.m`:

```
#import "Second.h"

@implementation Second

-(NSString*) message {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"Message is ", message];
}

@end
```

I'm trying to execute the following code, but it seems like the overridden method in `Second` is never executed.

```
First* first = [[First alloc] init];
[first setMessage:@"hello"];
NSLog(@"%@", [first message]); // "hello" expected

Second* second = (Second*) first;
NSLog(@"%@", [second message]); // "Message is hello" expected, but it's still "hello"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're actually casting a `First` as a `Second` (which is bad form); but the underlying type is still `First`, that's why you see the original `message` (from `First`). Alloc a `Second`, and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with how you override, but with how you allocate:

```
Second* second = [[Second alloc] init];
second.message = @"Hello";
NSLog(@"%@", [second message]);
```

When you cast `First*` to `Second*`, the object remains what it was - an instance of `First`. You need to allocate an instance of `Second` in order to see your override work.

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C, casts only make a statement to the compiler that an object is of a certain type. They do nothing to alter the actual object in any way. In down-casting `first` to a pointer to a `Second` instance, you have made an assertion to the compiler that is actually incorrect - because the object now pointed to by both `first` and `second` is still an instance of `First`. Hope this helps!